# Realm error: The lhs of the binary operator 'GreaterThan' should be a member expression.

Tags: xamarin, realm

I tried to get all persons who have dogs older than 10 using the following line of code :

```
var persons = realm.All<Person>()
.Where(person => person.Dogs.Count(dog=>dog.Age > 10) > 0);
```

But I got this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException:
The lhs of the binary operator 'GreaterThan' should be a member expression. 

Unable to process `person.Dogs.Count(dog => (dog.Age > 10))`
```

Does it mean that we are not able to filter on relations in `Realm` ?

Here are the models that I copied from [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#models):

```
public class Dog : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Person : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Dog> Dogs { get; }
}
```

Comment: LINQ support in Realm Xamarin : https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/d83bb320189421924933c9a7160b9bf307a48861/Doxygen/linq-support.md

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sorry, this type of query is not yet supported. We are working on improving LINQ coverage, but I'm afraid you won't be able to perform this particular query  in the near future.

Two workarounds that may or may not be applicable in your situation:

1) Add a boolean `HasOldDogs` property on your `Person` class. Note that in order to perform queries on it, it would have to be a persisted property so you would have to update it explicitly whenever you modify the `Dogs` property or any of the contained `Dog` instances.

2) Perform the query in memory. `var persons = realm.All<Person>().ToList().Where( ... )` will work. However, this will perform the query with LINQ to Objects in memory which works best if you don't have a massive number of `Person` instances.

If you can describe in more detail what your situation requires, we might be able to think up alternatives.

Comment: That's strange that it's not supported, using `Realm-Java` for Android you would be able to say `realm.where(Person.class).greaterThan("dogs.age", 10).findAll();` with [link queries](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, it's not because the Realm core doesn't support it, it's simply because the Realm Xamarin SDK is a bit behind. :-)

Answer (score 0):

may be you have to break your query to two queries instead of one.

Seems there are some issues with Realm that might require someone from Realm team to explain :)